# Vertical scrolling in responsive table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3.2.2 and the problem that i have is if a user wants to scroll the viewport up or down and tries to do that when he has clicked inside the table, then the scrolling doesn't work (nothing happens). If the user tries to scroll the viewport and he has clicked anywhere else apart from the table, then the viewport is scrolled.

You can see the attachment if it helps.

[image]

Andreas

Answer (score -1):

Just add the `display:block;` to the thead  tr and tbody. check the below example

```
thead,tr,tbody{
display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwmwc4k9/